# join lines with regex on notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, flat-file

well, i have 2 "sectors" of lines, which is separated by a line break

```
[RandomThings1]
[RandomThings1]
[RandomThings1]
[RandomThings1]

[RandomThings2]
[RandomThings2]
[RandomThings2]
[RandomThings2]
```

And i want to have this:

```
[RandomThings1][RandomThings2]
[RandomThings1][RandomThings2]
[RandomThings1][RandomThings2]
[RandomThings1][RandomThings2]
```

how can i do that?
if have another way to do that without regex or notepad++, will be welcome (tools for w indows)

Comment: Well, ***what have you tried and where are you stuck***?

Comment: **Google** is great for things like this...

Comment: Also what language you dont have any for the tags...

Comment: If the repetition of the things is always four you can do it with a regex replace: find `(.*)\r\n\1\r\n\1\r\n\1\r\n(\r\n)?(.*)\r\n\3\r\n\3\r\n\3\r\n`, replace with `\1\3\r\n\1\3\r\n\1\3\r\n\1\3\r\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex isn't the tool for this if 'RandomThings' are truly random.

You could do this with column select. Hold alt-shift and select all of your *2 values with the arrows. ctrl-x to cut. Then hold alt-shift and select the column to the right of the *1 values and ctrl-v to paste.

The key is to use column select before the cut, or it'll paste the whole list on every row.

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

Also note that the record/playback feature captures everything, including cut/paste, so often you hit record, perform the operation on the first value, then stop and playback to the end of the file. Very useful for repetitive operations, though you have to mind where you leave the cursor at the end.